# Parse date "2020-05-22T12:51:20.765111Z" to Instant in Java

Tags: java, datetime

How to parse `"2020-05-22T12:51:20.732111Z"` to Instant in Java?

I used:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
              startTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US))
          .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"))
          .toInstant()
```

but with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-05-22T12:51:20.732111Z' could not be parsed at index 24
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at Instant.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: My desired result should be Instant type

Comment: *"How to parse ... to Instant in Java?"* Call the `parse()` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Instant#parse(String)`:

```
Instant i = Instant.parse("2020-05-22T12:51:20.732111Z");
```

And if you want to convert it to your timezone:

```
ZonedDateTime z = i.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));
```

Printing it yields:

```
2020-05-22T08:51:20.732111-04:00[America/Toronto]
```

Comment: Wow, so simple answer:) Thank you!

Comment: That’s simple alright. @Matley I wondered how well you searched and researched before asking this question? Just remember next time, please